# Unable to set traffic class(IPV6_TCLASS) using setsockopt in windows

Tags: c++, ipv6, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to set `IPV6_TCLASS` in Windows, but for some reason I am getting an `WSAENOPROTOOPT` error ("An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call").

Below is the code to set `IPV6_TCLASS` class:

```
const int trafficClass = 232;
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_TCLASS, &trafficClass, sizeof(int)) < 0) 
{
  //some code
}
```

Comment: what error you gave? Do you check WSAGetLastError() value?

Comment: @Samini I used GetLastError() to log the error in Event Viewer.  The error logged is "An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.

Comment: What is the specific value you are trying to use for the traffic class? It is an eight-bit field, the first six bits are the DS value that ends in `0`, and the last two bits are the ECN. Not every possible DS value is valid. It looks like your `111 010` value is invalid, the closest being CS7 (`111 000`).

Comment: I am trying to set value 232(0xe8) which is 11101000

Comment: That is not a valid DS value. I mean, are you wanting one of the CS values (1 to 7),  an AF value (AF11, AF12, AF13, AF21, AF22, AF23, AF31, AF32, AF33, AF41, AF42, AF43), or something like BE or EF? What do you want from it? For example, the AF values normally have a higher precedence with a higher first digit, but are more likely to be dropped with a higher second digit, although the routers can be configured to do it differently.

Comment: There are specific values for DSCP. You can find [tables describing the values](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_0_4_s_v_1_3/qos/configuration/guide/n1000v_qos/n1000v_qos_6dscpval.html). Also, remember that setting a traffic class actually does nothing unless the routers have been configured to do something with them during congestion, but the default is to ignore the traffic class.

Comment: While the last bit is normally `0`, you can set that bit for experimental values. I'm not sure if the value is the problem you are experiencing, but setting it to what you are trying really will do nothing for you because there will be no routers configured to use that value, so the traffic class will essentially be BE (best effort, which is the default value of `00`).

Comment: I chose 0xe8 as traffic class as I found that value in one of my wireshark logs.  https://i.imgur.com/134nv6o.png  It clearly shows that 0xe8 is being used as traffic class.

Comment: Notice that is says `DSCP: Unknown`. That means the value is actually useless.

Comment: @RonMaupin Appreciate your help.  Can you suggest me any value for traffic class that might work ? I just want to be sure that this thing works.

Comment: Any of the ones in the list I linked. I'm not sure that is the source of your error, but I wanted to point out what are valid values. Also, remember that the traffic class does not do anything except on a router configured to do something about it, and only when there is network congestion on the router. By default, routers ignore the traffic class.